# Creating a Linux pipe using C++

Tags: c++, linux, shell, pipe

I am trying to create a simple shell program that includes pipes and redirects. For piping I currently have the following code:

```
//****Contains Prompts for User Input outside of 'If' statement********

if( contains(userInput, '|', str1, str2));

//Fork a child process
pid_t pid1 = fork();
if (pid1 == 0) {

//First child creates the pipe
pipe(pipeFD);

    //First child forks to a second child
    pid_t pid2 = fork();
    if(pid2 == 0){

    //Replaces standard output with pipe input
    dup2(pipeFD[1], 1);


    //Executes first command
    parseArgs(str1, argv);
    execvp(argv[0],argv);
    }else{wait(NULL);}

//Back in first child

    //Fork a third child
    pid_t pid3 = fork();
    if(pid3 == 0){

    //Third child replaces standard input with pipe output
    dup2(pipeFD[0],0);

    //Third child executes the second command
    parseArgs(str2, argv);
    execvp(argv[0],argv);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{wait(NULL);}

  }
}
```

As it stands right now, I've been using ls|grep as a test for my pipe. The output should look like this:

```
ls|grep hello
hello.cpp
helloworld.cpp
helloworld2.cpp
Enter a command:
```

instead, it looks like this:

```
ls|grep hello
Enter a command: hello.cpp
helloworld.cpp
helloworld2.cpp
```

Comment: Study existing Linux shells: most are free software, so you should download and study the source code (e.g. [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)...). And you could also use `strace`. Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: It's unclear what your program is doing, given the partial sources only. Further, `ls` and `grep` are both existing programms and how you expect to call your program with that is unclear, too.

Comment: As far as i see, the main program does not `wait` for the children before it outputs `Enter a command`

Comment: Geza Torok - That's the conclusion that I've come to as well, however I am not sure where to put a wait() in order to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured out what was wrong! Turns out I was trying to do too much by have 2 child processes nested within a child process. I have refined my piping process to only need 2 child processes within the parent process and it now works as intended:

```
 //Pass UserInput into the contains function to see if a pipe or redirect was used
if ( contains(userInput, '|')){

  split(userInput, '|', str1, str2);
  pipe(pipeFD);

    //Shell forks first child process
    pid_t pid1 = fork();
    if(pid1 == 0){

//First Child replaces standard output with pipe input
dup2(pipeFD[1],1);

//First Child Executes the first command
parseArgs(str1, argv);
execvp(argv[0],argv);

//Exit if execvp returns
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//Shell forks second child process
pid_t pid2 = fork();
if (pid2 == 0){

//Second Child replaces standard input with pipe output
    dup2(pipeFD[0],0);

//Second Child Executes the second command
parseArgs(str2, argv);
execvp(argv[0],argv);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}else{wait(0);}

}
```